# What will be the relation between Employees and Players, given that some players are also Employees?

Tags: database-design, erd

I have a requirement where I need to store information on Employees in a company that owns(?) a sports team and also store information on Players from other teams that are not Employees of this company. The Players in the team(i.e owned by the company) are also considered Employees hired by the company.

For the design, what I have done is create two Entities called Employees and Players and have a Player id key as FK in the Employees Entity. The Employee Entity also has Employees that are just employees and not players. With the player id fk, Employees that are Players will have a player id fk, while other employees will not. That way I have information about Employees, player or just normal employees, in Employee entity. And in the Players entity I only have information specific to all the players hired by the company or just other players from other teams(not owned by the company). Is this the right way to go? I haven't shown the subclass/subtype relation between Employees and Players entity because not every player in the Players entity is an Employee. Am I in the right direction?

I know this is not the very best explanation I guess but please do ask for any clarification. Thank you

Comment: There are employees and there are players. Some players are employees but there are employees that are not players and vice versa? You may concider a n-n relation, say employee_players. I guess that player alone is unique and that employee alone is unique as well, in this relation

Comment: You tagged your question with Mysql and sqlserver. The Sqlserver tag represents a product. If your intention was that MYSQL is an sql-server you should remove that tag

Comment: @Lennart just to confirm in this case Players will not be considered a subtype to Employee right?

Comment: Player is an attribute of the Employee or it is separate entity which is related to the employee entity as 1:(0 or 1)? Decide this firstly. PS. Is it possible that a player is not an employee? or it is absolutely impossibe?

Comment: @Akina Players is a separate Entity. And a player from the same company this database is for is considered as an employee while some other Players in the players entity are not Employees at all.

Comment: If so I agree with @Lennart - treate the relation as N:N, with intermediate junction table which have additional separate UNIQUE constraints for both employee_id and player_id for to provide strict 1:1 relation.

Comment: @Akina can you give an example of exactly why there's a N:N with unique constraints for both Emp_id and player_is? I'm not able to follow. Thanks.

Comment: @chimmy102, correct. One can exist without the other.

Comment: @chimmy102. An employee can be 0 or 1 players, a player can be 0 or 1 employees. Therefore they should both be unique individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can you give an example of exactly why there's a N:N with unique constraints for both Emp_id and player_is?

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE player (player_id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...);
CREATE TABLE junction (employee_id INT NOT NULL,
                       UNIQUE (employee_id),
                       FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (employee_id),
                       player_id INT NOT NULL,
                       UNIQUE (player_id),
                       FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES player (player_id));
```

Unique constraints forbid one employee to be two separate players and backward.

If a player is not an employee than junction table does not contain a row for him, and backward.

Comment: Just to confirm, we're not making employee_id and player_id primary keys because in that case a combination of both must be unique which would still result in, for eg, the employee being related to two separate players, right?

Comment: @chimmy102 Junction table does not need in primary key (first unique key will be used as clustered in this case), but you may to define `(employee_id, player_id)` as PK - it won't change anything except increasing storage size. But you **must** store both separate unique indices - composite PK does not provide separate values uniqueness.

Comment: @chimmy102, you can replace one of the UNIQUE constraints with a PRIMARY KEY. Why one of the candidate keys should be considered primary in SQL is still a mystery to me though.